# A set problem (inspired by geometry)

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Here's my problem:
say we have four sets of letters (abcdef) (abde) (abc) (ad). We can only add or subtract those sets in a way that (abc) + (ad) = (aabcd), (abcdef) - (abde) = (cf), but (abc) - (ad) is not allowed. Is it possible to get (b) only with these rules?

(inspired by a "find an area" geometry problem)
(is there a tag for these specific types of problems?)

Comment: The (abcdef) set is useless because it is the only set that has an 'f'. You would have to add and subtract that set an equal number of times for there to be no 'f' in the final result. I expect the answer to your question about getting (b) only is that it is impossible.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, once we see that we can't use (abcdef) at all, of the remaining sets (abc) is the only one that has a 'c', and (abde) is the only one that has an 'e', rendering both of those useless.

The remaining set is (ad) and obviously we can't get (b) by itself.